# easy tool for creating XML sitemaps? (constantly expanding site)

Tags: seo, google, php, sitemap

Does anyone recommend either

- a php script that I can run as a CRON

or

- somekind of thirdparty tool i can use
  to create sitemaps?

---

My website is events bases and so the pages are pretty temporal with 20+ new pages per day...

Google suggests these: http://code.google.com/p/sitemap-generators/wiki/SitemapGenerators
However they all look pretty old and i was wondering if there's some flashy new tool to do it with!

Comment: offering bounty because I am looking for a tool which will be able to take about 10,000,000 records (url, last updated) and produce a site map.

Comment: @user2804, my answer has been updated

Answer (score 7):

If you know how to do any server side programming you can write your own dynamic sitemap script which pulls the latest information from your database each time it is called. If your site doesn't update too frequently then you can cache the results and only update when necessary.

**update**

[Unlimited Sitemap Generator](http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/standalone-google-sitemap-generator.html) (Not free) This one can handle large sites with multiple sitemaps:

> Support of LARGE websites, dividing
>   the sitemap on the parts per 50,000
>   URLs each and creates a Sitemap Index
>   file according to the Google sitemap
>   protocol.

Comment: Also, if you're using a common CMS, chances are very high that there will already be a Sitemap generator available for it. At any rate, you should make sure that you do not use a crawler-based Sitemap generator, with a dynamic site like that you should try to always get the URLs directly from your internal data.

Comment: Giving the bounty for the script it yourself approach.

Answer (score 5):

Immediate solution would be an online sitemap generator:

http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/

Or as John Conde said, produce your own script that will either

a: trawl your www folder for html files, or

b: if your pages don't "physically" exist and are always dynamically generated, write a php script that will produce urls for all the pages that could exist.

Set up a cron job to call either script daily and that will produce a sitemap for all the pages vailable that day.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use xml-sitemaps but recently found : 
http://www.xmlsitemapgenerator.org
This has quite a lot more options and also has a  handy ping function.
they did disable the advanced features for a while and limited the number of pages, but they seem to be back now, although the limit is 50 pages. maybe if you ask nicely they will increase it!

Answer (score 0):

http://sitemap.keylimetie.com/ might not suit your needs, but I'll throw it out there in case anyone finds it useful.  I use it and am pleased with the results and it can be scheduled to run daily or weekly.